# optirun and ssh -X

Tags: ssh, xorg, opengl, bumblebee

I would like to run a remote OpenGL program through `ssh` tunneled with the `-X` option.

My laptop has Optimus so anything using OpenGL has to go through `optirun` (`bumblebee`). This would explain why I can't launch the program (`vmd` in my case, it says `can't open OpenGl GLX`).

Is there a way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is, but it isn't really usable.

OpenGL uses 3d acceleration, which is practically a chip of your actual, current video card. That means, that you can't do 3d accel on remote machines.

What you can do instead:

1. You could use the [mesa](http://www.mesa3d.org) version of the 3d accelerated libraries. It means software 3d rendering, without any acceleration. It were painfully slow even on the local machine - tunneled by ssh will be unusable.
2. You could run it on the local video card (you can start an X server even on this remotely), and connect to that with vnc.

(2) will be probably faster. Imho, it can be used in production environment only if there is an application with uses a little bit of 3d acceleration, but not very much (for example, some dos-based games or matlab).